# choosing certain columns of a dataframe from a file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df

```
Fruit   Apple   Orange   Banana  Pear

basket1   0        1       10     15

basket2   1        5        7     10

basket3   10       15       0      0
```

I have another dataframe select

```
type1   type2   type3

Apple   Apple   Orange

Orange  Pear    Apple

        Banana
```

I want to split the dataframe df into 3, based on the 3 columns in select.

Example df_type1 should be

```
Fruit   Apple   Orange   

basket1   0        1      

basket2   1        5      

basket3   10       15
```

df_type2 should be

```
Fruit   Apple   Banana  Pear

basket1   0       10     15

basket2   1        7     10

basket3   10       0      0
```

I have loaded df and select into pandas with the following code.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("df.txt",sep = "\t",header =0)
select = pd.read_csv("select.txt",sep ="\t",header =0)
```

I am unsure of the next merge command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list of values from your dataframe select:

```
type1 = list(select['type1'].dropna())
type2 = list(select['type2'].dropna())
type3 = list(select['type3'].dropna())
```

The use these lists to select the slice of the df

```
 df_type1 = df[type1]
 df_type2 = df[type2]
 df_type3 = df[type3]
```

df_type1

```
    Apple   Orange
0   0   1
1   1   5
2   10  15
```

and so on...

EDIT:

You can use isin() to handle the KeyError

```
type1 = select.type1[select.type1.isin(df.columns)].tolist()
type2 = select.type2[select.type2.isin(df.columns)].tolist()
type3 = select.type3[select.type3.isin(df.columns)].tolist()

df_type1 = df[type1]
df_type2 = df[type2]
df_type3 = df[type3]
```

Comment: I get a Key error when I try df_type1 = df[type1],  KeyError: "['Apple  ' 'Orange '] not in index"

Comment: Can you print the output of df.columns.tolist()?

Comment: Yes, the output is ['Fruit','Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Pear']

Comment: The code works fine here, there has to be some typo. Since the column names are matching, is the first df named df (without any capital letters)?

Comment: The code works fine for the example above. However, in the case there if type1 has Apple,Orange and Tangerine (which is not in df), the code gives the error KeyError: "['Tangerine'] not in index". Is there is a way to tell the code to ignore the rows in select which are not columns in df? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Given the specified dataframes

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,1,10,15],[1,5,7,10],[10,15,0,0]], columns=['Apple','Orange','Banana','Pear'], index=['basket1','basket2','basket3'])

select = pd.DataFrame([['Apple','Apple','Orange'],['Orange','Pear','Apple'],['','Banana','']], columns=['type1','type2','type3'])
```

Solution:

```
new_dfs = {}

for col in select.columns:

    fruit_list = []

    for index in select.index:

        if select.loc[index,col] != '':

            fruit_list.append(select.loc[index,col])

    new_dfs[col] = df[[x for x in fruit_list]]
```

That will give you a dic (new_dfs) with each desired dataframe within it.
Sample outputs:

```
new_dfs['type1']
```

[image]

```
new_dfs['type2']
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd create another dataframe with a multiindex

```
pd.concat(
    [df[select.T.stack()[t]] for t in select],
    axis=1, keys=select
)

  type1        type2              type3      
  Apple Orange Apple Pear Banana Orange Apple
0     0      1     0   15     10      1     0
1     1      5     1   10      7      5     1
2    10     15    10    0      0     15    10
```

---

***break it down***

- `pd.concat` will join on an axis
- `select.T.stack()` turns `select` into something more convenient to slice
- `for t in select` loops through column names in `select`
- `keys=select` the keys parameter takes a list like thing.  In that context, `select` will return the column names.

---

To access the way you want.

```
d1 = pd.concat(
    [df[select.T.stack()[t]] for t in select],
    axis=1, keys=select
)

d1['type1']

   Apple  Orange
0      0       1
1      1       5
2     10      15
```

---

Access what you want one at a time without storing a new structure

```
df[select.T.stack().type1]

   Apple  Orange
0      0       1
1      1       5
2     10      15
```

Comment: @Ssank see if my updated post satisfies what you are after.

Comment: When I run the concat command I get an error Traceback (most recent call last):
KeyError: "['Apple  ' 'Orange '] not in index"